# Possible issues with SSD SATA3 drive

Tags: linux, arch-linux, ssd, sata

While investigating the issue with my SATA3 SSD drive being recognized as SATA2 (for some reason had to change SATA ports to fix it) I noticed the following messages when I run:

```
$ dmesg | grep ata3.00
[    0.980592] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    0.980594] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    0.980596] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    0.980712] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    0.980795] ata3.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[    0.980797] ata3.00: ATA-9: SAMSUNG MZ7PD128HAFV-000H7, XXXXXXX, max UDMA/133
[    0.980798] ata3.00: 250069680 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    0.981070] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    0.981072] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    0.981073] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    0.981174] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    0.981225] ata3.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[    0.981227] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

My architecture:

```
$ uname
3.13.8-1-ARCH
```

My concern is the line where it says that system **failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1**

Is this something I need to be concerned with?

My system is Asrock Extreme4 mb with SAMSUNG MZ7PD128HAFV-000H7 SSD SATA3 drive on Arch Linux OS.

**Update 1**

I run SysLinux on my machine and below is the output of the same command (no failure messages):

```
root@sysresccd /root % dmesg | grep ata3
[    1.166153] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0336000 port 0xf0336200 irq 42
[    1.470696] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.471504] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.471507] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.471710] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    1.472032] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.472166] ata3.00: ATA-9: SAMSUNG MZ7PD128HAFV-000H7, SN, max UDMA/133
[    1.472359] ata3.00: 250069680 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    1.472760] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.472761] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.472762] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    1.472920] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.472946] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
```

I compared SATA power profiles on both OSes under `/sys/class/scsi_host/host(0-7)` and they set to **max_performance**.

What else can I check on both OSes and configure Arch so that this failure message would go away?

**Update 2**
Looks like this issue only appears in newer kernels...

I tried with Ubuntu Live CD 12.04, 13.10, and 14.04:
I was able to see this issue in 14.04 but not in other 2 versions.

I then run diff for the kernel config files but I can't figure out the exact change that affects me...

[Ubuntu 13.10 kernel config file](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/saucy/amd64-config.flavour.generic)

[Ubuntu 14.04 kernel config file](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/trusty/amd64-config.flavour.generic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known error in Samsung SSDs: The drives do not properly implement queued trim commands.

However, Ubuntu (and probably most other Linux distributions) now implement trim as a cronjob to improve performance, so this is not of any practical concern.

For more details, see the kernel bug on this: 
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72341

The reason the error did not appear in older kernels is that these do not try to use the buggy function of the drive, they thus never see the error. Even newer kernels (4.0 and forward) know that the drives have this error, so the error will not be shown for the drive in the future.